# java override during object creation

Tags: java, overriding, instantiation

in the following java code a JButton is created but at the same time one of its methods gets overridden.
Qestion: is there a name for overriding in this way while creating the object?

the code:

```
   JButton myButton;
   myButton = new JButton ("ok"){

        @Override
        public void setText(String text) {
            super.setText(text +", delete");
        }
```

the jbutton's label is now "ok, delete"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's an anonymous class. From [Java in a Nutshell](http://hell.org.ua/Docs/oreilly/javaenterprise/jnut/ch03_12.htm)

> An anonymous class is a local class
>   without a name. An anonymous class is
>   defined and instantiated in a single
>   succinct expression using the new
>   operator. While a local class
>   definition is a statement in a block
>   of Java code, an anonymous class
>   definition is an expression, which
>   means that it can be included as part
>   of a larger expression, such as a
>   method call. When a local class is
>   used only once, consider using
>   anonymous class syntax, which places
>   the definition and use of the class in
>   exactly the same place.

It's a common means of providing a specialisation of a base class without explicitly defining a new class via the `class` expression.