# Migrating Java Anonymous class to JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I want to move this piece of Java code to a JSP file.

```java
IReader reader = new SomeReader<SomeClass>() {

    @Override
    protected SomeClass createNode() {
        return new SomeClass();
    }
};
```

I get this error:

> `Unable to compile class for JSP:`
>
> `Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody`

I don't see this syntax ([Java Anonymous Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1504261)) being supported in JSP. What is an alternative to this?

Using Java 8 - Zulu JDK (old project).

Comment: [Not using scriptlets at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340291/jsp-what-is-wrong-with-scriptlets-and-what-to-use-instead) (I personally try to get rid of JSP entirely).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks for the reference. I am using this in an old project where standard JSP is our best bet for having REST API endpoints which we feed to different frontends. I found a solution (read: workaround) to this which I will add as an answer shortly.